# $3\times 3$ magic squares consisting of entries of a dense set $D\subseteq \mathbb{N}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, recreational-mathematics

**Starting point.** The struggle for a magic square consisting of distinct square numbers is still ongoing, but it has produced an amusing landmark result called the [Parker square](https://www.bradyharanblog.com/the-parker-square). One of the issues is that square numbers are very scarce - which leads to the following question.

**Problem.** A *$3\times 3$ magic square* is a $3\times 3$ integer matrix with all entries being distinct, such that all row sums, column sums, and diagonal sums are equal.

We call a set $D\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ *dense* if $$\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|D\cap \{1,\ldots, n+1\}|}{n+1} > 0.$$

If $D\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is dense, is there always a $3\times 3$ magic square with all the entries lying in $D$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

By Szemerédi's theorem, your set contains an arithmetic progression of arbitrary length. In particular, it contains a progression of length 9, say it's $d_1,\ldots,d_9$. Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
d_2 & d_7 & d_6\\
d_9 & d_5 & d_1\\
d_4 & d_3 & d_8
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a magic square.